# flutter Not getting Notification in Oppo and Vivo

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send notification. It is working fine on Samsung and mi devices but, not getting a notification in Oppo Vivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPPO and VIVO always have issue with Notifications. They restrict app from doing any background task for saving battery. This is not just with Flutter but with native development too.

Solution:

Turn off battery saving mode of the mobile.
Remove app from restricting using battery in background.
Turn on Autostart for the app.

You will find respected intents for these setting screens.

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues in Oppo user, but ignore this problem because they had restrict the app for saving battery feature. Even app like Whatsapp, notification become delay in oppo.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33083754)